Driver Error: NVIDIA-SMI failed because it couldn’t communicate with the NVIDA Driver
as part of my bachelor thesis, I am working on deploying an local LLM, but unfortunately I am having issues with my NVIDIA Driver.
When I type “nvidia-smi” I get the error message, that it couldnt communicate with the driver. I’ve found several solutions in different forums, but unfortunately none of them worked for me.
Ive deployed a VM in the vmWare Environment. The VM contains 4 Tesla T4s, each with 16 GB VRAM in a 16Q Grid.
The Ubuntu Version is 24.04 and the Kernel Version is 6.8
The installed NVIDIA Driver Version is 550.67
The NVIDIA Bug Report is a 2.3 GB File, so I cant upload it here. I've uploaded it in my OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj2agVoBjnDdhsh24vlS19WXzal-3A?e=KMZgOk
I’ve also tried it before on a VM with Ubuntu 22.04.
I would be very happy, if someone could help me, because it would help me with my bachelor thesis

You may be better off with Ubuntu 22.04 as 24.04 might require that smi be updated.
